# Suppress Spring Advice in some cases

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I have a method and around advice on that method. When that method gets called, advice is getting applied on it.

```
methodA();
```

In a special case, when that method gets from another method, I would like to suppress advice getting applied on it. When `methodA()` gets called from `methodB()`, I would like to suppress applying advice on `methodA()`. Is this possible?

```
methodB() {
   methodA();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to. It's done automatically. Spring AOP works through proxies and you can't proxy calls within the class.

Comment: Didn't get your point. Do you mean if there is proxy in side proxy, it will call only outside proxy ?

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying). It also explains the limitations of Spring proxies.

Comment: does `methodA()` and `methodB()` belong to same class or not ?